# Flask send_file not opening a file

Tags: python, flask

hello I am new to flask and i have to generate a pdf file and then send it to the client side with send_file(). The problem is that the flash function is executed but the send_file function is not opening the file that I am trying to send. This is my code:

```
def print_file_pdf(printer, file_content, options, html):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
        f.write(file_content)
        f.flush()
        flash("Fichier PDF généré", category="success")
    return send_file("file.pdf", mimetype='image/pdf', conditional=True)
```

I am completely new to this so sorry if I made a stupid mistake that will trigger you :-)

Comment: You should probably be using the name attribute of f to get the name of the temporary file e.g. `name = f.name` and then `return send_file(name....`

Comment: Also by default, NamedTemporaryFile created files are deleted as soon as you close them. You'd need to used `NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)` to keep the file for later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in my comments, your use of NamedTemporaryFile (a new thing to me) is likely the major problem here. By default NamedTemporaryFile created files are deleted straight away once you close the file.

You can change this default behaviour using `delete=False` as a keyword argument to NamedTemporaryFile.

Also if you want to send the file created, you need to pass that file's path to the `send_file` function. Get the name by accessing the `f.name` attribute before you leave the `with` context manager.

Obviously I can't test your code as you have only shared a small snippet but the following should work.

```
def print_file_pdf(printer, file_content, options, html):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
        f.write(file_content)
        f.flush()
        flash("Fichier PDF généré", category="success")
        name = f.name
    return send_file(f.name, mimetype='image/pdf', conditional=True)
```

Alternatively, `send_file` can take a "file-like object" so try

```
def print_file_pdf(printer, file_content, options, html):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
        f.write(file_content)
        f.flush()
        flash("Fichier PDF généré", category="success")
        return send_file(f, mimetype='image/pdf', conditional=True)
```

Comment: You were right, the temporary file was deleted before it could be sent, i tried the code you posted and now it works just fine, thank you very much :-)